# Netteza SQL ALTER TABLE in stored procedure alternative?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza

I want to alter a table within a `For` loop in Netteza SQL. I know that Netteza does not allow `alter table` in a stored procedure. As quoted:

> "These SQL commands are also prohibited within the body of a Netezza stored procedure."

Are there any alternatives for doing so? I am a beginner in Netteza. I also don't know if my loop format is correct?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_Automate_Table"()
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE

vSQL1  varchar(30000)  ;

BEGIN

FOR i in 2011..2014
 LOOP
 For j in 1..12
 Loop       
    call "SP_Count"(i, j);
    vSQL1:='alter table X add columnX INT';
    ....
      ...
       .. 
    EXECUTE  immediate vSQL1;

  END LOOP;
END LOOP;

END;
END_PROC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with v7.1 you can declare an AUTOCOMMIT ON block in a stored procedure, and in this block you can call statements that would otherwise be prohibited within a stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADMIN.SP_ALTER_LOOP(INTEGER, INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    pStartVal ALIAS FOR $1;
    pCount ALIAS FOR $2;    
    vSQL varchar(30000);

BEGIN

BEGIN AUTOCOMMIT ON
for i in 1 .. pCount LOOP
    vSQL := 'ALTER TABLE CLAIM_' || pStartVal + i-1 || ' ADD COLUMN (COL2 BIGINT);';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;
END LOOP;

END;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Prior to v7.1, I don't know of a way you can alter a table structure from with a stored procedure.

Note that in the general case of ALTER TABLE (whether scripted like this or manual), be sure to perform a groom of each altered table after the ALTER operation.

```
GROOM TABLE tablename VERSIONS;
```

Comment: Oh, nice. That gives me a good reason to get away from 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop statement is [syntactically correct](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_iterative_control.html), but there is no way to issue alter statements from within nzplsql.

I would suggest doing a bash script as an alternative, repeatedly calling `nzsql`.

```
for i in $(seq 2011 2014); do
  for j in $(seq 1 12); do
    nzsql -c "call \"SP_Count\"($i, $j);"
    nzsql -c "alter table X add columnX INT;"
  done
done
```

I can't really imagine a use case where you'd want to dynamically add columns by calling a stored procedure from within a database that couldn't also be covered by doing it outside the database.

Comment: Thanks, It helped. Even though the other answer was more convenient.

Comment: Here's our use case. We have a database upgrade script to go from one version of our software to another and it happens to have been written as a single SQL file. One of the constraints is that we have a single file that can be executed multiple times without raising any errors. For this we've had to create stored procedures called CREATE_TABLE_IF_NOT_EXISTS(), ADD_COLUMN_IF_NOT_EXISTS() and RENAME_COLUMN_IF_EXISTS(). It's getting a bit more complicated than we expected and we might be better off writing a batch file instead (Windows application) or some hybrid, but we do have a use case.

Comment: Right, I understand, but as I mentioned, I can't imagine a case where you need to do it *in* the database where you can't also do it *outside* of it. Most of these tasks are not things where some user needs access to it. My point is that a scripting environment is a superset of the functionality. Also that ^ sounds horrible. It would be far better to check for presence and notify/throw errors than silently fix things, especially when performing upgrades.